# Using G-WAN for Web services

Tags: android, web-services, postgresql, nginx, g-wan

I am considering to use G-WAN to serve web services dedicated to a mobile application (android, iOS) due to a potential high concurrency (number of users, number of requests).

The services will be interfaced to a PostgreSQL server, so I would like to know if C is a good choice to develop the solutions or if there are better alternatives ?

I don't have much knowledge in C, and as the job needs to be quickly done, I might leave G-WAN to use another web server like ningx, but then which framework could I use to develop these web services ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The services will be interfaced to a PostgreSQL server, so I would like to know if C is a good choice to develop the solutions

Like G-WAN, PostgreSQL is written in C to be as fast as possible.

And, with G-WAN, you will be able to write your application in any mix of scripts written in C, C++, Objective-C and Java (PHP soon).

Besides the performance, there are not many Web servers around there able to give you that kind of wide choice.

Comment: You are giving Bias information as you ARE an author of G-WAN.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/G-WAN_vs_Nginx

I would recommend against G-WAN.  I did an exhaustive study on the matter and I find that the vast majority of G-WAN information is written by G-WAN authors themselves.  Look actual implementation documentation.  Look up your server tech and G-WAN.  I use ubuntu, I was pretty hard pressed to find much of anything.

Comment: I don't think recommending AGAINST using something because of a lack of "outside documentation" is a good reason for doing so.  G-WAN has excellent documentation, specifically for implementation:  http://gwan.ch/api, and for developers: http://gwan.ch/developers.  There's also a wiki for G-WAN too: http://www.gwanserver.com, which has been built and is maintained completely away from the creator of G-WAN.

Comment: The vast majority of information is necessarily writen by the manufacturers of all products.

Comment: That's simply not true.  You are touting a product because you made the product not because it actually performs well.  In actual studies its not all it claims to be.  It's all drastically lacking in features  even when compared to other light web servers.